# How to configure the settings in visual studio code for prettier to work for react.js

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, prettier

When I press `save` the code goes like below.
I don't want `prettierrc.json` to act neither do I want `ESLINT`.

I have installed visual code extension `Prettier Code Formatter` and changed `editor.formatonSave` to `true`

```
       "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "[javascript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
      },
      "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
      },
      "[typescript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
      },
      "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      }
    }
```

Example

```
    import React from "react";
    import "./App.css";

    import Ball from "./Ball";
    import Lottery from "./Lottery";

    function App() {
      return ( <
        div className = "App" >
        <
        Lottery / >
        <
        Lottery title = "Mini Daily"
        maxNum = {
          10
        }
        maxBalls = {
          4
        }
        /> <
        /div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did, with the Prettier extension installed I added this to my settings.json:

`"[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
  }`

I actually have mine set to true because I do want it to format my .jsx files (notice I use the extension .jsx not .js).  But if you set it to false you should be good to go in your situation.